# ImportError: GSSAPIProxy requires the Python gssapi library

Tags: python, importerror, gssapi, krb5.ini

Hello after updating to python 3.11.5 i am getting this particular import error on all of my scripts. Anyone knows what i need to install/update for this

```
 ImportError: GSSAPIProxy requires the Python gssapi library: No module named 'krb5'
```

i already installed gssapi but keep getting this error on all of my script.